# Parsing .log file in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, logging

I need to parse a log file in C# like this

[image]

For every WORK NUMBER: for example 0000613216 I need to get array of those values in columns (FOCUS1, FOCUS2 and so on)

Every entry for WORK NUMBERS are divided by single line

I tried converting it to CSV for easier parsing, but that doesn't work
If you have any idea how it could be done please tell me
Thanks for any responses.

```
______________________________________________________________________________________________________

DATE:                    6/12/2023 12:00:04 AM
WORK NUMBER:             0000613200

SERIES  Z POS   FOCUS0  FOCUS1  FOCUS2  FOCUS3  FOCUS4
1   10.00525    0.08801 0.07229 0.06474 0.10287 0.11546 
1   9.99325     0.09923 0.08002 0.07114 0.11579 0.12486 
1   9.98125     0.11740 0.08878 0.07880 0.13022 0.12551 
1   9.96925     0.14366 0.09946 0.08740 0.14346 0.11689 
1   9.95725     0.17671 0.11388 0.09733 0.14505 0.10312 
1   9.94525     0.18247 0.13156 0.10948 0.13173 0.09144 
1   9.93325     0.15665 0.15209 0.12640 0.11421 0.08211 
1   9.92125     0.13193 0.16052 0.14542 0.09985 0.07498 
1   9.90925     0.11292 0.14441 0.15793 0.08842 0.06883 
1   9.89725     0.09777 0.12294 0.14723 0.08005 0.06289 
1   9.88525     0.08494 0.10384 0.12389 0.07234 0.05801 
2   9.91750     0.15404 0.29308 0.33028 0.31821 0.43277 
2   9.92550     0.36046 0.44745 0.47603 0.43807 0.52971 
2   9.93350     0.55016 0.56322 0.56229 0.52031 0.56136 
2   9.94150     0.65980 0.57930 0.59376 0.53092 0.52922 
2   9.94950     0.65657 0.48450 0.53619 0.38995 0.39549 
2   9.95750     0.55660 0.32726 0.41730 0.21084 0.24739 
2   9.96550     0.41468 0.16724 0.26466 0.13177 0.11899 


______________________________________________________________________________________________________

DATE:                    6/12/2023 12:00:23 AM
WORK NUMBER:             0000613201

SERIES  Z POS   FOCUS0  FOCUS1  FOCUS2  FOCUS3  FOCUS4
1   10.20063    0.09741 0.08879 0.06386 0.08820 0.11901 
1   10.18863    0.11367 0.10012 0.06947 0.09867 0.12474 
1   10.17663    0.13742 0.11374 0.07600 0.11149 0.11811 
1   10.16463    0.16615 0.13124 0.08345 0.12626 0.10573 
1   10.15263    0.17902 0.15007 0.09228 0.14213 0.09284 
1   10.14063    0.16302 0.15662 0.10338 0.15402 0.08372 
1   10.12863    0.13577 0.14421 0.11795 0.14401 0.07610 
1   10.11663    0.11864 0.12340 0.13812 0.12318 0.07038 
1   10.10463    0.10213 0.10618 0.15575 0.10577 0.06480 
2   10.26062    0.05706 0.05607 0.04630 0.05516 0.08047 
2   10.24862    0.06210 0.06060 0.04857 0.05984 0.08668 
2   10.23663    0.06823 0.06635 0.05145 0.06528 0.09235 
2   10.22463    0.07605 0.07310 0.05476 0.07214 0.10108 
2   10.21262    0.08565 0.08050 0.05847 0.07914 0.10986 
2   10.20062    0.09828 0.08846 0.06359 0.08876 0.12022 
2   10.18863    0.11316 0.09944 0.06934 0.09824 0.12436 
2   10.17663    0.13634 0.11400 0.07548 0.11026 0.11848 
2   10.16462    0.16477 0.13138 0.08326 0.12540 0.10555 
2   10.15262    0.18048 0.14967 0.09214 0.14279 0.09337 
2   10.14063    0.16334 0.15569 0.10288 0.15373 0.08413 
2   10.12863    0.13666 0.14495 0.11837 0.14473 0.07645 
2   10.11662    0.11905 0.12363 0.13783 0.12373 0.07074 
2   10.10462    0.10243 0.10643 0.15505 0.10623 0.06520 
2   10.09263    0.09048 0.09323 0.15678 0.09319 0.06040 
2   10.08063    0.07926 0.08394 0.13654 0.08374 0.05590 
3   10.11537    0.24263 0.46639 0.41908 0.52584 0.54745 
3   10.12337    0.43610 0.55359 0.51809 0.57243 0.56675 
3   10.13137    0.58813 0.52539 0.57941 0.54004 0.46843 
3   10.13937    0.64659 0.42439 0.50392 0.40485 0.32114 
3   10.14737    0.58643 0.30037 0.38134 0.24828 0.17790 
3   10.15537    0.46908 0.18555 0.24859 0.14911 0.11164 
4   10.07533    0.00100 0.00100 0.11460 0.06485 0.05216 
4   10.08333    0.00100 0.06702 0.13194 0.08097 0.11828 
4   10.09133    0.03628 0.11365 0.16202 0.17184 0.22641 
4   10.09933    0.16632 0.17358 0.22704 0.30140 0.35232 
4   10.10733    0.13130 0.32844 0.33016 0.43749 0.46087 
4   10.11533    0.28051 0.48495 0.42963 0.53827 0.55699 
4   10.12333    0.45336 0.54168 0.53006 0.56906 0.55310 
4   10.13133    0.59028 0.51895 0.57321 0.52561 0.45447 
4   10.13933    0.63433 0.40818 0.50346 0.39461 0.31065 
4   10.14733    0.57823 0.28429 0.37443 0.24878 0.17688 
5   10.09656    0.15875 0.20865 0.31227 0.30260 0.26387 
5   10.10456    0.14141 0.34588 0.41908 0.42738 0.38271 
5   10.11256    0.28856 0.49461 0.51833 0.53059 0.49212 
5   10.12056    0.47197 0.53969 0.57803 0.56609 0.57182 
5   10.12856    0.59686 0.50214 0.52577 0.53905 0.51705 
5   10.13656    0.64447 0.38819 0.41699 0.41435 0.39881 
5   10.14456    0.58610 0.28069 0.29345 0.27295 0.25628 


______________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: It's hard to give an accurate answer since the image doesn't tell us what chars are between the values, e.g. spaces or tabs etc. After finding the work number, you should be able to jump ahead to the table of data, and parse each row by splitting the values (most likely by tabs/spaces) and reading until you hit a blank row.

Comment: Do you only have the logfile? Or do you have control over the code that _writes_ those logs?

Comment: @P.Magnusson And if in the logfile are multiple work numbers and for each there are those values, how should I store those values like a dictionary of work number and list of lists?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I have only the logfile

Comment: _"how should I store those values"_ - where are you planning to store them? If you write them into a SQL Database, I'd honestly just have a column for that number. Same for CSV. I don't see much benefit in normalizing that, except there is a good reason to do so, that's not obvious.

Comment: ^^ Whereas if you store them in a DocumentDB , you can have the WorkNumber and Date in a base document and the "Items" in a collection of Sub-Documents.

Comment: Could you [edit] the Q to include a text-version of that log?

Comment: So, a naive first attempt could look like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhYRQa (but it is far from production-quality)

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are asking someone to write the code for you. This is typically not well received. Try adding the code you have already written to get input on that. And maybe people have ideas to write it in a different and more optimal way.